# Maven2 applying filtering to the file under pom type packaging

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, multi-module

I am new to maven. I want to use filtering in a multimodule project. The packaging type of the parent pom is set to pom. The structure of the project is as follows:

```
pom.xml
     |
     |______MODULE1
     |       |
     |       pom.xml
     |       File1_needed_to_be_filtered
     |
    File2_needed_to_be_filtered
```

Please note that Module1 is also multimodule project.
So please tell me how can I apply filtering to file1 and file2. And if i apply filtering to file1, then where will the processed file be stored (Since pom file whose packaging type is pom do not create any folder named target!)
Please help me as this is very critical to me and this issue is addressed nowhere else on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) - with a 'dir' format (although if there is ever more than one file, it might make sense to make it an archive of some kind).  The [descriptor format](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) allows you to filter.  This should work with the pom and file hierarchy you describe above.

However, I would recommend putting these in sibling modules instead of the parent.  This keeps the logic out of your aggregator pom, and (once you start doing that) you might decide it's easier to use the assembly to distribute them along with your other components, which you'd want a module for anyway.

Comment: Hi Zac, Thanks for the answer. Actually i have already opted the second option. However i would like to try your first option whenever got some time.

Answer (score 0):

To have Maven filter resources when copying, set filtering to `true` for the resource directory in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filterineg>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

But if you want to filter resources, don't put them in a project with a packaging of type `pom`, this doesn't make sense (for the reason you gave yourself). Actually, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve (since you know this is not how things work).

Comment: Hey pascal first of all thanks for your interest. Actually I need to use multi-module project that is why i am using pom packaging type. Also the file to be filtered is not present in src/main/resources folder, it is in the root of parent folder. I cant change the hierarchy of the files that is why i am going through all these problems.

Comment: @Hamit The pom packaging is fine (and actually required) for aggregating modules of your multi-modules setup but I'm afraid you won't be able to filter resources in such modules. What I don't get is how these "filtered" resources are supposed to be used. What are you going to do with them since they are in a module of type pom?

Comment: These resources are actually property files. These files(file1 and file2) will be copied to remote location along with the other files generated after filtering and compilation. These configuration files are also used by sub-modules. I need to set the values in these files manually, so i was thinking of using filtering. But I am afraid that there is any way to do so.